# Why does the initialization to `weak` return `nil` in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references

Why does the initialization to `weak var` return the variable as `nil` while the initialization to the usual `var` return the expected result? In the following code on `ViewController.swift`:

```
weak var myButton: UIButton!
var myButtonNotWeak: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    myButton = UIButton(frame: frame)
    myButtonNotWeak = UIButton(frame: frame)
    print("\(myButton), \(myButtonNotWeak)")
}
```

This logs the following to the console:

```
nil, <UIButton: 0x7f946bc424a0; frame = (0 0; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f946bc42920>>
```

But why does the first return `nil`? I think if you define a variable as `weak`, then when the view controller that defined the "weaked variable" (`self` in this case) is gone, the "weaked variable" is gone in accordance with it. However, I believe I don't remove the instance of the ViewController in the code not assign `nil` to it, especially within its `viewDidLoad()` method.

So if I get it correctly, why does the "weaked variable" return `nil` when initiated? When I use it with `@IBOutlet`, then it doesn't become `nil` (but I don't need to explicitly inistantiate it, though). And should I define the instance variable without `weak` when I want to inistantiate it from within code, especially within `viewDidLoad()`?

I want to retain the variable outside of `viewDidLoad()` because I want to refer to the instance from other methods. What's the best way in this case?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC.pdf page 62: the newly allocated object has no strong references to it, so it is immediately deallocated and someObject is set to nil.

Comment: In Swift there are two types of weak references: weak which is the same as in Objective-C and unowned. The difference is that an unowned reference can never be nil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`weak` means that variable doesn't retain the object and it will be deallocated if there are no other strong references to it. `@IBOutlet` `weak` variables are not nil, because those views have strong references from view controllers view hierarchy.

You have to refer with strong reference to your button and add it to view hierarchy before you can assign it to weak property, or simply don't use `weak` property.

Comment: curiously. so in which case should I have to use weak? it seems that i should always use strong if cycle reference would not happen